# SQL Server Case statements partly working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I cam across a problem while writing a Case statement in SQL Server(2017).
Below is the code. The first four **when** statements **(inside the 2nd case)** execute perfectly fine. The last two however don't seem to give me any results.

```
CASE 
   WHEN cd.IsRequired=0 THEN 'Deliverable Not Required'
   WHEN cd.IsRequired=1 THEN
      CASE 
          WHEN cd.Planned_Date = null THEN 'Date Missing'
          WHEN cd.Actual_Date = cd.Planned_Date THEN 'Completed - On Time'
          WHEN cd.Actual_Date > cd.Planned_Date THEN 'Completed - Late'
          WHEN cd.Actual_Date < cd.Planned_Date THEN 'Completed - Early'
          WHEN cd.Actual_Date = NULL AND cd.Planned_Date < GETDATE() THEN 'Incompleted - Late'
          WHEN cd.Actual_Date = NULL AND cd.Planned_Date >= GETDATE() THEN 'Incompleted'

      END
END AS [STATUS]
```

These are the columns... Sorry I wasn't able to format it better, but stack didn't allow me to upload pictures.

```
**PLANNED_DATE**                  |               **ACTUAL_DATE**

2018-07-06                        |               2018-07-06

NULL                              |                NULL 

2018-07-20                        |               2018-07-18

2018-07-27                        |               NULL

2018-08-17                        |               NULL

2018-07-13                        |               2018-07-13
```

So in the status column, this is what my output came out to be:

```
Status:
Completed - On Time
Deliverable Not Required
Completed - Early
NULL
NULL
Completed - On Time
```

The first null in the status column should be **'Incompleted - Late'** and the other null should **'Incompleted'**. However as you can see, I am not seeing those results. Any help would be appreciated, again sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: `is null`, not `= null`.

Comment: omg that worked like a charm! thank you!! @GordonLinoff

Comment: You can use =null for string null. Otherwise to check null you need to use is null

Comment: I see, thank you for the tip! @saravanatn